# Delay execution while file uploading

Tags: php, while-loop

My form uploads a file to be added to a mail created with PHPMailer.

Unfortunately, the mail isn't being sent and I think that might be because it's being sent too soon in execution. So what I wanted to do was to add in a small loop to effectively pause further execution until the file has been uploaded:

```
while (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'][$first_name.' CV'], $target_path))
{
    sleep(1);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'][$first_name.' CV'], $target_path))
    {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['upload'][$first_name.' CV'])." has been uploaded";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
```

This is what I've come up with but I'm not exactly sure what it's doing here.

Please clarify on the following for me:

1. Is the declaration of `!move_uploaded_file...` uploading the file at the start of the loop?
2. If yes, is the file being uploaded on every iteration through the loop?
3. Is the declaration of `move_uploaded_file...` in the `if` statement within the loop also uploading the file or is it just checking that the file has been uploaded?
4. What's the best way to handle this sort of thing? I'm sure this isn't it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have observed a similar problem when uploading video files. Supposedly `move_uploaded_file` is synchronous, although after `move_uploaded_file` returns true, the script runs sending a response to the client indicating the load succeeded, which then makes another request to download for viewing on the page, yet I would get a video load error.  Simply adding a 3 second delay after `move_uploaded_file` returns (a hack) before sending the response fixes the problem, although I haven't determined why this delay should be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP script will not execute before the file upload is finished. You are trying to solve the wrong problem.

The web server handles the request, which includes handling and waiting for the file data to upload. Only after the complete request has been received by the web server will it invoke your PHP script. (That is, unless you're using some unusual web server.) Anything present in `$_FILES` is guaranteed to be there ***now***.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, well it is moving the file anyway. Once it has moved the file I guess it will return false.
2. Yes it is trying to move the file on every iteration
3. This is also trying to move the file. You are executing the method not declaring it.
4. move_uploaded_file is a synchronous call. Just use this code below, it will enter the if statement if the file was uploaded successfully. I am guessing this is a red herring for your issue

code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'][$first_name.' CV'], $target_path))
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['upload'][$first_name.' CV'])." has been uploaded";
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: You lost me at the red herring issue, but luckily I haven't applied the while loop yet. All I currently have is the if statement, but it seems like the file hasn't been uploaded (the folder in the server is empty)...

Comment: I meant this is probably not why your mail isnt being sent !