# PHP Mailer doesn't send email after move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmailer

I have the following code to save the attachment and send it via email (PHP Mailer).

```
    $filedata['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];    
    $path = "files/".md5($i.$filedata['name'].time()).".".pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);

    $mail->AddAttachment( $path, $filedata['name']);
```

The problem is, the mail **sometimes**, not always, is sent without the attachment (however, the file is uploaded). I suppose, the problem is in `move_uploaded_file`, as the email is sent **before the file moved**.

Is there some kind of callback to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path)){

    $mail->AddAttachment( $path, $filedata['name']);

}
```

You can use this.

Comment: Will it wait until the file moved?

Comment: Yes. You will get success when file is moved succesfully. @Leeloo

Comment: In my case, the file was uploaded. But the email wasn't send. Probably, it took longer for the file to be moved (2 Mb)

Comment: The size of file doesn't matter. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110103/delay-execution-while-file-uploading

Answer (score 1):

You need to check first if the attachment is uploaded successfully or not

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($path, $filedata['name']);
}
else {
    echo "Upload failed";
}
```

Edited:

Or you can try to catch the error

```
try {

    /*
     *
     * Your mail code here
     * ..........
     */

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
    $mail->AddAttachment($path, $filedata['name']);
    $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); // Error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: The problem is, the file uploaded. But wasn't sent via email

Comment: Yes, the file is uploaded on the server

Comment: And the email fails sometimes, not always

Comment: Can you show me the full code of your email function code? and you need to make sure the mail header  is `Content-type`

Answer (score 0):

put mail function inside the if condition:

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path)){

    $mail->AddAttachment( $path, $filedata['name']);
}
```

Before sending the mail we should check the is uploaded or not first.

Comment: Will it wait until the file moved?

Comment: :) Sorry, We write same code here your answer published first